# Is It Ok to Move Boost Library Installation To New Computer Without Reinstalling

Tags: c++, boost

I originally installed boost per the instructions at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/bbv2/installation.html
I transferred most of my Windows user profile to a new computer, which contained a folder called CodeLibs. This folder is where I originally installed boost (in place of PREFIX in above documentation).
I compiled a project that uses the serialization library, and I didn't receive any errors.

My question is, is there any reason to go through the documented installation process again or is the above directory transfer sufficient?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying should be fine, so long as the target architecture is the same.

Boost doesn't need to be "installed" in the typical way.  There are no registry settigs to set, no COM servers to install, no daemons to set up.  Nothing like that.

The install process you went through originally mostly consisted of compiling code.  That code, once compiled, was then copied to some destination folder and some environment variables might have been updated.

None of this is truly necessary, but once you get the code on your target machine you might have to tweak a few paths etc so that the compiler can find the headers and libs (if any libs are needed), and executables can find the shared libraries.

Assuming you have a high level of proficiency with such things -- as is suggested by the fact that you were able to install it the first time at all -- I'm sure none of this will be a major challenge for you.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the architecture is the same and yes, the include and lib paths have been updated :-)